# how to use for in a list with lambda?

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, for-loop, lambda

This is my code:

```
a_list = [lambda x: x**n for n in range(1, 5)]
for q in a_list:
    print(q(3))
```

I want to list 3 to the power of 1 to 4, but the result is:

```
27
27
27
27
```

Could you help me fix it? Thank you very much!  (I use python 3)

Comment: BTW, fun little abuse to avoid `lambda` entirely (though it prevents callers passing custom objects with their own `__pow__` definitions), running faster by virtue of not needing Python level code at all: `[n.__rpow__ for n in range(1, 5)]`

Answer (score 2):

You want to preserve the argument as a default in the lambda:

```
[lambda x, *, n=n: x**n for n in range(1, 5)]
```

And then:

```
>>> for q in a:
    print(q(3))


3
9
27
81
```

Using the [`functools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#module-functools) module:

```
from functools import partial
[partial((lambda n, x: x**n), n) for n in range(1, 5)]
```

Note that in the partial, the order of the variables were switched because the [partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) passes in the first argument. (Parentheses added around the lambda for clarity).

Comment: Since this is Python 3, `[lambda x, n=n: x**n for n in range(1, 5)]` can be expressed more safely as `[lambda x, *, n=n: x**n for n in range(1, 5)]`; the `*,` makes `n` keyword-only, so it can't be passed by accident if a second positional argument is given.

Answer (score 0):

Rassar answer is good!

Another way to do it is used [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) in order to set the `n`:

```
from functools import partial

a_list = [partial(lambda n, x: x**n, n) for n in range(1, 5)]
for q in a_list:
    print(q(3))
```

partial is taking only part of the arguments (here it's `n`) and applies it to the function and returns a new function in which `n` is already set.

Pay attention that in order to do that we needed to have `n` as the first argument of the lambda!